# How do I reconcile the output of a decision tree visual vs the output of the DecisionTreeClassifier class?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, prediction, cart

I have a decision tree model stored in `dt`. I also plotted and can visually see the decision tree itself. Given a new, unseen customer, I can use the visual tree to get the predicted class of the customer (class A or class B, for example).

However, I can also run `dt.predict_proba(data) >= threshold` and vary the threshold and get different class outputs. If I set the threshold to 0.9, that same customer could be classified differently from what the visual tree would output.

The problem I have is reconciling these two concepts. Ultimately my goal is to minimize false positives, and I can do that by varying the threshold, but then this wouldn't match the output of the visual tree itself, which I'm guessing is basing its decisions on a 0.5 threshold? I feel like both the visual tree and the model itself should be one and the same.

I'm so confused. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're almost certainly right that the plotting code is using a 0.5 threshold to map tree leaves to labels.  You're also correct that threshold tuning is really important.  If you'd like the picture to match your (correct) procedure, you're probably going to have to open the hood and modify the plotting code.